# How do I express 67, 69, 83, 84, 86, 87, 88, 93 with 2,0,2,2 only?

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Use $2, 0, 2, 2$ and some mathematical operators to express numbers from $1$ to $100$.

Operators: $+$, $-$, $\times $, $\div$, ( ), √ (square root), $^$ (power), $!$ (factorial), $!!$ (double factorial), nr (permutation) , nr (combination)

Update:88 done,7 remain

**Note: exactly 3 twos and one zero can be used. You can use .2 as 0.2, and you can concatenate numbers like 202**

I have done $93%$ of them, and I don’t know $7$ of them.
Please help me. Here are a few examples:

$$1=2\times 0+2/2 \quad 2=-20+22 \quad 3=2\times 0!/2+2 \quad 4=2\times 0+2+2$$
$$5=2-0!+2+2 \quad 6=2+0+2+2 \quad 7=2+0!+2+2 \quad 8=2\times 2\times 2+0$$
$$9=2\times 2\times 2+0! \quad 10=\left(\sqrt{20/2}\right)^2 \quad 11=(2+2)!/2-0! \quad 12=(2+2)!/2-0$$
$$13=(2+2)!/2+0!$$
$$14=(2+2)!!+(2+0!)!$$
$$15=2^{2\times 2}-0!$$
$$16=2^{2+2}+0$$
$$17=2^{2+2}+0!$$
$$18=(2+2)!-(2+0!)!$$
$$19=22-2-0!$$
$$20=-2-0+22$$
$$21=-2+0!+22$$
$$22=2\times 0+22$$
$$23=(2+2)!-2+0!$$
$$24=2-0+22$$
$$25=(2+2)!+2-0!$$
$$26=(2+2)!+2+0$$
$$28=22+(2+0!)!$$
$$29=(.2)^{-0!}+(2+2)!$$
$$30=(2+2)!+(2+0!)!$$
$$31=(.2)^{-2}+(2+0!)!$$
$$32=2^{2+2+0!}$$
$$33=2^{\sqrt{(.2)^{-2}}}+0!$$
$$34=((2+0!)!)^2-2$$
$$35=\sqrt{(.(0!))^{-2}}+(.2)^{-2}$$
$$36=(20-2)\times 2$$
$$37=((.2)^{-0!})!!+22$$
$$38=20\times 2-2$$
$$39=((.2)^{-0!})!!+(2+2)!!$$
$$40=20\times \sqrt{2+2}$$
$$41=20\times 2+\underbrace{\sqrt{\sqrt{\dots2}}}_{\infty}$$
$$42=20+22$$
$$43=22\times 2-0!$$
$$44=22\times 2-0$$
$$45=22\times 2+0!$$
$$46=(22+0!)\times 2$$
$$47=(2+2+2)!!-0!$$
$$48=(2+2+2)!!+0$$
$$49=(2+2+2)!!+0!$$
$$50=(.2)^{-2}\times 2+0$$
$$51=(.2)^{-2}\times 2+0!$$
$$52=((.2)^{-2}+0!)\times 2$$
$$53=((2+0!)!)!!)+\sqrt{(.2)^{-2}}$$
$$70=(2+\sqrt{(.2)^{-2}})/(.(0!))$$
$$71=\sqrt{(2+\sqrt{(.2)^{-2}}))!+0!}$$
$$80=(2+2)!!\times \sqrt{(.(0!))^{2}}$$
$$81=(2+0!)^{2+2}$$
$$88=P^{\sqrt{(.(0!))^{-2}}}_2-2$$
$$89=P^{\sqrt{(.2)^{-2}}}_2-0!$$
$$90=((2+0!)!)!/(2+2)!!$$
$$91=P^{\sqrt{(.2)^{-2}}}_2+0!$$
$$92=P^{\sqrt{(.(0!))^{-2}}}_2+2$$
$$95=C^{20}_2 /2$$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123453/discussion-on-question-by--how-do-i-express-67-69-83-84-86-87-88-93-wi).

Comment: Note that this was cross-posted on Puzzling.SE as [Make 1-100 using 2 0 2 2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/110019/32666).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: I have just figured out 88
$$88=P^{\sqrt{(.(0!))^{-2}}}_2-2$$

Answer (score 3):

***Edit:** added alternate solutions with alternate operations (see comment discussion)*.

---

It seems that this is impossible, given your current specification of rules.

I wrote a python program to solve this. It returned:

```
unknowns: 7 [67, 69, 83, 84, 86, 87, 93]
```

Below is the full output. (Notation: `2i = 1` = $\underbrace{\sqrt{\sqrt{\dots2}}}_{\infty}$.)

*(To avoid issues with extremely large numbers, largest absolute values of numerators/denominators of arguments to $a^b$ and to $n!$ were bounded by $10^4$, and largest output value of any given binary operation was bounded by $\pm 10^{20}$.)*

*(WLOG we can use any subset of $\{2,0,2,2\}$ as "$+(0\cdot 2)$" absorbs excess elements.)*

```
[1] 1 = (0!)
[1] 2 = 2
[2] 3 = (2 - (-(2i)))
[2] 4 = ((-2) * (-2))
[2] 5 = ((-(2i)) / (-(.2)))
[2] 6 = (((0!) - (-2))!)
[3] 7 = ((((-2) * (-2))!!) + (-(2i)))
[2] 8 = (((-2) * (-2))!!)
[3] 9 = ((((-2) * (-2))!!) - (-(2i)))
[2] 10 = ((-(0!)) / (-(.(2i))))
[3] 11 = (((-2) / (-(.2))) - (-(2i)))
[3] 12 = ((((-(2i)) / (-(.2)))!) * (.(2i)))
[3] 13 = ((((-(0!)) / (-(.2)))!!) + (-2))
[3] 14 = ((((-(2i)) / (-(.2)))!!) + (-(0!)))
[2] 15 = (((-(2i)) / (-(.2)))!!)
[3] 16 = ((((-2) * (-2))!!) * 2)
[3] 17 = ((((-(2i)) / (-(.2)))!!) - (-2))
[3] 18 = (((-2) / (-(.(2i)))) + (-2))
[3] 19 = (((-2) / (-(.(2i)))) + (-(0!)))
[2] 20 = ((-2) / (-(.(2i))))
[3] 21 = (((.(2i)) - (-2)) / (.(0!)))
[2] 22 = 22
[3] 23 = (22 - (-(0!)))
[2] 24 = (((-2) * (-2))!)
[2] 25 = ((-(.2)) ^ (-2))
[3] 26 = (((-(.2)) ^ (-2)) - (-(0!)))
[3] 27 = (((-(.2)) ^ (-2)) - (-2))
[3] 28 = ((((-2) * (-2))!!) C 2)
[4] 29 = (((2 - (-(2i))) - (.(2i))) / (.(0!)))
[3] 30 = ((2 - (-(2i))) / (.(2i)))
[4] 31 = (((2 - (-(2i))) / (.(2i))) - (-(0!)))
[3] 32 = (2 ^ ((-(0!)) / (-(.2))))
[4] 33 = ((2 ^ ((-(0!)) / (-(.2)))) - (-(2i)))
[4] 34 = ((2 ^ ((-(0!)) / (-(.2)))) - (-2))
[4] 35 = (((-(((0!) - (-2))!)) + (-(2i))) / (-(.2)))
[3] 36 = ((-(((0!) - (-2))!)) ^ 2)
[4] 37 = (((-(((0!) - (-2))!)) ^ 2) - (-(2i)))
[4] 38 = ((20 C 2) * (.2))
[4] 39 = ((((-2) * (-2)) - (.(2i))) / (.(0!)))
[3] 40 = ((((-2) * (-2))!!) / (.2))
[4] 41 = ((((-2) * (-2)) - (-(.(0!)))) / (.(2i)))
[4] 42 = ((((.(2i)) - (-2)) * (-2)) / (-(.(0!))))
[4] 43 = ((((-(0!)) / (-(.(2i)))) C 2) + (-2))
[3] 44 = ((-22) * (-2))
[3] 45 = (((-(0!)) / (-(.(2i)))) C 2)
[3] 46 = (((((0!) - (-2))!)!!) + (-2))
[3] 47 = ((((2 - (-(2i)))!)!!) + (-(2i)))
[2] 48 = ((((0!) - (-2))!)!!)
[3] 49 = ((((2 - (-(2i)))!)!!) - (-(2i)))
[3] 50 = (((-2) / (-(.2))) / (.2))
[4] 51 = (((-((-(.(0!))) ^ (-2))) + (-2)) / (-2))
[4] 52 = ((((-(0!)) / (-(.2))) - (-(.2))) / (.(2i)))
[4] 53 = (((-(2i)) / (-(.2))) + ((((0!) - (-2))!)!!))
[4] 54 = ((((0!) - (-2))!) - (-(((2 - (-(2i)))!)!!)))
[4] 55 = ((((.(2i)) - (-(0!))) / (-(.(2i)))) / (-(.2)))
[3] 56 = ((((-2) * (-2))!!) P 2)
[4] 57 = (((((-2) * (-2))!!) P 2) - (-(0!)))
[4] 58 = (((-(((0!) - (-2))!)) / (-(.(2i)))) + (-2))
[4] 59 = (((-(((-(0!)) / (-(.2)))!)) - (-2)) / (-2))
[3] 60 = ((-(((0!) - (-2))!)) / (-(.(2i))))
[4] 61 = (((-(((-(0!)) / (-(.2)))!)) + (-2)) / (-2))
[4] 62 = (((-(((0!) - (-2))!)) / (-(.(2i)))) - (-2))
[4] 63 = (((-2) ^ (((0!) - (-2))!)) + (-(2i)))
[3] 64 = ((-2) ^ (((0!) - (-2))!))
[4] 65 = (((((-(0!)) / (-(.2)))!!) + (-2)) / (.2))
[4] 66 = ((((-(0!)) / (-(.(2i)))) - (-2)) C 2)
['?'] 67 = ?
[4] 68 = (((-2) / (-(.(2i)))) + ((((0!) - (-2))!)!!))
['?'] 69 = ?
[4] 70 = (((-(((0!) - (-2))!)) + (-(2i))) / (-(.(2i))))
[4] 71 = (((-(((2 - (-(2i)))!)!)) * (-(.(2i)))) + (-(0!)))
[3] 72 = ((-(((2 - (-(2i)))!)!)) * (-(.(2i))))
[4] 73 = (((-(((2 - (-(2i)))!)!)) * (-(.(2i)))) - (-(0!)))
[4] 74 = (((-(((-(2i)) / (-(.2)))!!)) / (-(.2))) + (-(0!)))
[3] 75 = ((-(((-(2i)) / (-(.2)))!!)) / (-(.2)))
[4] 76 = (((((-(0!)) / (-(.2)))!!) - (-(.2))) / (.2))
[4] 77 = (((-((((-2) * (-2))!!)!!)) + (-(0!))) * (-(.2)))
[4] 78 = (((((-2) * (-2))!!) / (.(0!))) + (-2))
[4] 79 = (((-(((-2) * (-2))!!)) + (.(2i))) / (-(.(0!))))
[3] 80 = ((((-2) * (-2))!!) / (.(0!)))
[4] 81 = (((((-2) * (-2))!!) / (.(0!))) - (-(2i)))
[4] 82 = (((((-2) * (-2))!!) / (.(0!))) - (-2))
['?'] 83 = ?
['?'] 84 = ?
[4] 85 = (((-(((-(0!)) / (-(.2)))!!)) + (-2)) / (-(.2)))
['?'] 86 = ?
['?'] 87 = ?
[4] 88 = ((((-(0!)) / (-(.(2i)))) P 2) + (-2))
[4] 89 = ((((-(0!)) / (-(.(2i)))) P 2) + (-(2i)))
[3] 90 = (((-(0!)) / (-(.(2i)))) P 2)
[4] 91 = (((((-(2i)) / (-(.2)))!!) + (-(0!))) C 2)
[4] 92 = ((((((0!) - (-2))!)!!) + (-2)) * 2)
['?'] 93 = ?
[4] 94 = ((((((0!) - (-2))!)!!) + (-(2i))) * 2)
[4] 95 = (((-(((2 - (-(2i)))!)!!)) * (-2)) + (-(0!)))
[3] 96 = ((-(((2 - (-(2i)))!)!!)) * (-2))
[4] 97 = (((-(((2 - (-(2i)))!)!!)) * (-2)) - (-(0!)))
[3] 98 = (((-(.(0!))) ^ (-2)) + (-2))
[3] 99 = (((-(.(0!))) ^ (-2)) + (-(2i)))
[2] 100 = ((-(.(0!))) ^ (-2))
```

Notice that the output has more unary minuses than needed. I guess the sets were sorted from low to high, so those were the first found solutions.

Also notice that the square root was never needed, other than in the limit expression.

---

**Edit $1$:** If you ban the infinite square root limit, then more numbers become impossible.

```
unknowns: 11 [54, 67, 68, 69, 79, 83, 84, 86, 87, 93, 97]
```

Full list of alternate solutions not using the limit `2i`:

```
[1] 1 = (0!)
[1] 2 = 2
[2] 3 = ((0!) - (-2))
[2] 4 = ((-2) * (-2))
[2] 5 = (r((-(.2)) ^ (-2)))
[2] 6 = (((0!) - (-2))!)
[3] 7 = ((((-2) * (-2))!!) + (-(0!)))
[2] 8 = (((-2) * (-2))!!)
[3] 9 = (((-(.2)) - (-2)) / (.2))
[2] 10 = (r((-(.(0!))) ^ (-2)))
[3] 11 = ((-22) / (-2))
[3] 12 = ((-(((-2) * (-2))!)) / (-2))
[3] 13 = ((((-(0!)) / (-(.2)))!!) + (-2))
[3] 14 = (((r((-(.2)) ^ (-2)))!!) + (-(0!)))
[2] 15 = ((r((-(.2)) ^ (-2)))!!)
[3] 16 = (((r((-(.2)) ^ (-2)))!!) - (-(0!)))
[3] 17 = (((r((-(.2)) ^ (-2)))!!) - (-2))
[3] 18 = (((-(.2)) - (-2)) / (.(0!)))
[4] 19 = ((((-(.2)) / 2) - (-2)) / (.(0!)))
[2] 20 = 20
[3] 21 = (22 + (-(0!)))
[2] 22 = 22
[3] 23 = (22 - (-(0!)))
[2] 24 = (((-2) * (-2))!)
[2] 25 = ((-(.2)) ^ (-2))
[3] 26 = (((-(.2)) ^ (-2)) - (-(0!)))
[3] 27 = (((-(.2)) ^ (-2)) - (-2))
[3] 28 = ((((-2) * (-2))!!) C 2)
[4] 29 = (((-(((0!) - (-2))!)) - (-(.2))) / (-(.2)))
[3] 30 = ((-((r((-(.2)) ^ (-2)))!!)) * (-2))
[4] 31 = ((2 ^ (r((-(.2)) ^ (-2)))) + (-(0!)))
[3] 32 = (2 ^ (r((-(.2)) ^ (-2))))
[4] 33 = ((2 ^ (r((-(.2)) ^ (-2)))) - (-(0!)))
[4] 34 = (((-(((0!) - (-2))!)) ^ 2) + (-2))
[4] 35 = (((((-2) * (-2))!!) + (-(0!))) / (.2))
[3] 36 = ((-(((0!) - (-2))!)) ^ 2)
[4] 37 = ((((-(0!)) / (-(.2)))!!) - (-22))
[4] 38 = ((20 C 2) * (.2))
[4] 39 = (((((-2) * (-2))!!) / (.2)) + (-(0!)))
[3] 40 = ((((-2) * (-2))!!) / (.2))
[4] 41 = (((((-2) * (-2))!!) / (.2)) - (-(0!)))
[4] 42 = ((((-2) * (-2)) / (.(0!))) - (-2))
[4] 43 = (((r((-(.(0!))) ^ (-2))) C 2) + (-2))
[3] 44 = ((-22) * (-2))
[3] 45 = ((r((-(.(0!))) ^ (-2))) C 2)
[3] 46 = (((((0!) - (-2))!)!!) + (-2))
[4] 47 = (((r((-(.(0!))) ^ (-2))) C 2) - (-2))
[2] 48 = ((((0!) - (-2))!)!!)
[4] 49 = (((r((-(.(0!))) ^ (-2))) + (-(.2))) / (.2))
[3] 50 = (((-2) / (-(.2))) / (.2))
[4] 51 = (((-((-(.(0!))) ^ (-2))) + (-2)) / (-2))
[4] 52 = ((((-(.2)) ^ (-2)) - (-(0!))) * 2)
[4] 53 = ((r((-(.2)) ^ (-2))) + ((((0!) - (-2))!)!!))
['?'] 54 = ?
[4] 55 = ((((-2) / (.2)) + (-(0!))) / (-(.2)))
[3] 56 = ((((-2) * (-2))!!) P 2)
[4] 57 = (((((-2) * (-2))!!) P 2) - (-(0!)))
[4] 58 = (((((-(0!)) / (-(.2)))!) / 2) + (-2))
[4] 59 = (((((-(0!)) / (-(.2)))!) + (-2)) / 2)
[3] 60 = (((r((-(.2)) ^ (-2)))!) / 2)
[4] 61 = ((((r((-(.2)) ^ (-2)))!) / 2) - (-(0!)))
[4] 62 = (((((-(0!)) / (-(.2)))!) / 2) - (-2))
[4] 63 = (((((-2) * (-2))!!) ^ 2) + (-(0!)))
[3] 64 = ((-2) ^ (((0!) - (-2))!))
[4] 65 = (((-(((-(0!)) / (-(.2)))!!)) - (-2)) / (-(.2)))
[4] 66 = (((r((-(.(0!))) ^ (-2))) - (-2)) C 2)
['?'] 67 = ?
['?'] 68 = ?
['?'] 69 = ?
[4] 70 = ((((r((-(.2)) ^ (-2)))!!) + (-(0!))) / (.2))
[4] 71 = (r((((r((-(.2)) ^ (-2))) - (-2))!) - (-(0!))))
[4] 72 = ((((((-2) * (-2))!!) + (-2))!) * (.(0!)))
[4] 73 = (((-(((-(0!)) / (-(.2)))!!)) / (-(.2))) + (-2))
[4] 74 = (((-(((-(0!)) / (-(.2)))!!)) - (-(.2))) / (-(.2)))
[3] 75 = ((-(((-(0!)) / (-(.2)))!!)) / (-(.2)))
[4] 76 = ((-(20 P 2)) * (-(.2)))
[4] 77 = (((-((((-2) * (-2))!!)!!)) + (-(0!))) * (-(.2)))
[4] 78 = (((((-2) * (-2))!!) / (.(0!))) + (-2))
['?'] 79 = ?
[3] 80 = ((((-2) * (-2))!!) / (.(0!)))
[4] 81 = ((((-2) / (.2)) - (-(0!))) ^ 2)
[4] 82 = (((-(((-2) * (-2))!!)) + (-(.2))) / (-(.(0!))))
['?'] 83 = ?
['?'] 84 = ?
[4] 85 = (((-(((-(0!)) / (-(.2)))!!)) + (-2)) / (-(.2)))
['?'] 86 = ?
['?'] 87 = ?
[4] 88 = (((r((-(.(0!))) ^ (-2))) P 2) + (-2))
[4] 89 = ((((-2) / (-(.2))) P 2) + (-(0!)))
[3] 90 = (((-2) / (-(.2))) P 2)
[4] 91 = ((((r((-(.2)) ^ (-2)))!!) + (-(0!))) C 2)
[4] 92 = (((-((((0!) - (-2))!)!!)) - (-2)) * (-2))
['?'] 93 = ?
[4] 94 = ((((((0!) - (-2))!)!!) * 2) + (-2))
[4] 95 = ((20 C 2) / 2)
[3] 96 = (((((0!) - (-2))!)!!) * 2)
['?'] 97 = ?
[3] 98 = (((-(.(0!))) ^ (-2)) + (-2))
[4] 99 = ((((-(.2)) / 2) ^ (-2)) + (-(0!)))
[2] 100 = ((-(.(0!))) ^ (-2))
```

Where we can see that this time, the square root is actually useful.

---

**Edit $2$:** If you allow subfactorial $!n$, gamma $\Gamma(n)$ and overline ($.\overline{2}=0.222\dots=2/9]$), then only one number remains impossible.

```
unknowns: 1 [93]
```

Below is the full list of alternate solutions *(`,n` stands for overline `.n̅`)*.

```
[1] 1 = (0!)
[1] 2 = 2
[2] 3 = ((0!) - (-2))
[2] 4 = ((-2) * (-2))
[2] 5 = ((-(!2)) / (-(.2)))
[2] 6 = ((2 - (-(!2)))!)
[3] 7 = (((-(!2)) / (-(.2))) - (-2))
[2] 8 = (((-2) * (-2))!!)
[2] 9 = ((-(0!)) / (-(,(!2))))
[2] 10 = ((-2) / (-(.2)))
[3] 11 = (((-2) / (-(.2))) - (-(!2)))
[3] 12 = (((0!) - (-(.2))) / (.(!2)))
[3] 13 = ((((-(0!)) / (-(.2)))!!) + (-2))
[3] 14 = ((((-(!2)) / (-(.2)))!!) + (-(0!)))
[2] 15 = (((-(!2)) / (-(.2)))!!)
[3] 16 = (((-(,2)) - (-2)) / (,(0!)))
[3] 17 = (((-(,(!2))) - (-2)) / (,(!2)))
[2] 18 = ((-2) / (-(,(!2))))
[3] 19 = (((-2) / (-(,(!2)))) - (-(0!)))
[2] 20 = 20
[3] 21 = (((-2) - (.(!2))) / (-(.(0!))))
[2] 22 = 22
[3] 23 = (((-(.2)) ^ (-2)) + (-2))
[2] 24 = (Γ((-(!2)) / (-(.2))))
[2] 25 = ((-(.2)) ^ (-2))
[3] 26 = (((-(.2)) ^ (-2)) - (-(0!)))
[3] 27 = (((0!) - (-2)) / (,(!2)))
[3] 28 = ((((-2) * (-2))!!) C 2)
[4] 29 = ((((.(!2)) + (,2)) / (.(!2))) / (,(0!)))
[3] 30 = (((0!) - (-2)) / (.(!2)))
[4] 31 = ((2 ^ ((-(!2)) / (-(.2)))) + (-(0!)))
[3] 32 = (2 ^ ((-(!2)) / (-(.2))))
[4] 33 = ((2 ^ ((-(!2)) / (-(.2)))) - (-(0!)))
[4] 34 = ((-(((-2) / (-(,(0!)))) P 2)) * (-(,(!2))))
[4] 35 = ((((,2) + (-(!2))) / (.2)) / (-(,(0!))))
[3] 36 = (((-2) / (-(,(!2)))) * 2)
[4] 37 = ((((-2) * (-2)) + (,(0!))) / (,(!2)))
[4] 38 = ((((-2) / (.(0!))) * (-2)) + (-2))
[4] 39 = ((((-2) / (.(0!))) * (-2)) + (-(!2)))
[3] 40 = (((-2) / (.(0!))) * (-2))
[4] 41 = ((((-2) / (.(0!))) * (-2)) - (-(!2)))
[3] 42 = ((!((-(0!)) / (-(.2)))) + (-2))
[3] 43 = ((!((-(!2)) / (-(.2)))) + (-(!2)))
[2] 44 = (!((-(!2)) / (-(.2))))
[3] 45 = (((-(.2)) + (,2)) ^ (-(!2)))
[3] 46 = ((!((-(!2)) / (-(.2)))) - (-2))
[3] 47 = (((((0!) - (-2))!)!!) + (-(!2)))
[2] 48 = ((((0!) - (-2))!)!!)
[3] 49 = ((((2 - (-(!2)))!)!!) - (-(!2)))
[3] 50 = (((-2) / (-(.2))) / (.2))
[4] 51 = (((-((-(.(0!))) ^ (-2))) + (-2)) / (-2))
[4] 52 = ((((-(.2)) ^ (-2)) - (-(0!))) * 2)
[3] 53 = ((-(!((2 - (-(!2)))!))) * (-(.2)))
[3] 54 = (((2 - (-(!2)))!) / (,(0!)))
[4] 55 = ((((-(0!)) / (,(!2))) + (-2)) / (-(.2)))
[3] 56 = ((((-2) * (-2))!!) P 2)
[4] 57 = (((((-2) * (-2))!!) P 2) - (-(0!)))
[4] 58 = (((-((2 - (-(!2)))!)) - (-(.2))) / (-(.(0!))))
[4] 59 = (((((-(0!)) / (-(.2)))!) + (-2)) / 2)
[3] 60 = (((2 - (-(!2)))!) / (.(0!)))
[4] 61 = (((((-(0!)) / (-(.2)))!) - (-2)) / 2)
[4] 62 = (((((0!) - (-2))!) - (-(.2))) / (.(!2)))
[4] 63 = ((((-(0!)) / (,(!2))) - (-2)) / (-(,(!2))))
[3] 64 = ((-2) ^ (((0!) - (-2))!))
[4] 65 = ((((-(0!)) / (,2)) + (-2)) / (-(.(!2))))
[4] 66 = ((((0!) - (-(.2))) / (.(!2))) C 2)
[4] 67 = (((-(((-(0!)) / (-(.2)))!!)) + (,(!2))) / (-(,2)))
[4] 68 = ((-(((-2) / (-(,(0!)))) P 2)) * (-(,2)))
[4] 69 = ((r((Γ(((-2) * (-2))!!)) - (-(0!)))) + (-2))
[4] 70 = ((((-(0!)) / (,(!2))) - (-2)) / (-(.(!2))))
[3] 71 = (r((Γ(((-2) * (-2))!!)) - (-(0!))))
[3] 72 = ((-(((-2) * (-2))!!)) / (-(,(!2))))
[4] 73 = (((((-2) * (-2))!!) + (,(0!))) / (,(!2)))
[4] 74 = (((((-(!2)) / (-(.2)))!!) / (.2)) + (-(0!)))
[3] 75 = ((((-(!2)) / (-(.2)))!!) / (.2))
[4] 76 = (((((-(!2)) / (-(.2)))!!) / (.2)) - (-(0!)))
[4] 77 = (((-((((-2) * (-2))!!)!!)) + (-(0!))) * (-(.2)))
[4] 78 = (((((-2) * (-2))!!) + (-(.2))) / (.(0!)))
[3] 79 = (((,(0!)) ^ (-2)) + (-2))
[3] 80 = ((-((((0!) - (-2))!)!)) * (-(,(!2))))
[2] 81 = ((,(0!)) ^ (-2))
[3] 82 = (((,(!2)) ^ (-2)) - (-(!2)))
[3] 83 = (((,(!2)) ^ (-2)) - (-2))
[4] 84 = ((((,(!2)) ^ (-2)) - (-2)) - (-(0!)))
[4] 85 = ((((-(,(!2))) - (-2)) / (-(.(0!)))) / (-(,2)))
[4] 86 = (((!((-(0!)) / (-(.2)))) * 2) + (-2))
[4] 87 = (((!((-(0!)) / (-(.2)))) * 2) + (-(!2)))
[3] 88 = ((!((-(0!)) / (-(.2)))) * 2)
[4] 89 = ((((-2) / (-(.2))) / (,(!2))) + (-(0!)))
[3] 90 = (((-2) / (-(.2))) / (,(!2)))
[4] 91 = ((((-(0!)) / (,(!2))) - (.(!2))) / (-(.(!2))))
[4] 92 = (((-((((0!) - (-2))!)!!)) - (-2)) * (-2))
['?'] 93 = ?
[4] 94 = (((-((((0!) - (-2))!)!!)) * (-2)) + (-2))
[4] 95 = (((-((((0!) - (-2))!)!!)) * (-2)) + (-(!2)))
[3] 96 = ((-((((0!) - (-2))!)!!)) * (-2))
[4] 97 = (((-((((0!) - (-2))!)!!)) * (-2)) - (-(!2)))
[3] 98 = (((.(!2)) ^ (-2)) + (-2))
[3] 99 = ((-22) / (-(,2)))
[2] 100 = ((-(.(0!))) ^ (-2))
```

**Edit $3$:** Allowing arbitrary roots solves the last number, $93$. See [this answer on Puzzling.SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/109730/32666).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123454/discussion-on-answer-by-vepir-how-do-i-express-67-69-83-84-86-87-88-93-wi).

Comment: @伍逸朗 To find out which operations can allow 93 to be made in a non-trivial way, is actually a good question I decided to post on puzzling: [Make 93 using 2, 0, 2, 2 and a least powerful set of operations](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/109714/32666).

Comment: I tried the recurring one, and it is 1/9 off the target.

Comment: I don’t have enough reputation to comment lol

Comment: So, what is .2th root of 2 is allowed?

Comment: That is a nice idea, to extend the square root to other roots. With this new rule, we can solve 93. You can maybe include the solution to 93 using that rule, in your post here or your answer here. *(Btw, If you feel like this question has been solved, you can accept an answer by clicking the checkmark.)*

Comment: So, I think 2023 can deal with all 1-100, am I correct?